# Get multiple images through Json

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, foreach

I'm trying to loop through all available images and submit them to client side. With my code below, I'm only able to get one when I upload multiple images at one time. The exact same code is also in my php page and shows all images perfectly. So I assume its something to do with my attempt of constructing an array, or the loop itself. ;}

I'm aware my script is currently vulnerable to sql injection, securing comes later.;)

```
$sqlhhh = "SELECT * FROM userphotos WHERE photo_name='".$row['photo_title']."' 
AND photo_ownerid='".$row['streamitem_creator']."' 
AND photo_datetime='".$row['streamitem_timestamp']."' ORDER BY photo_id DESC";
$resulthhh = mysqli_query ($mysqli,$sqlhhh)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
$photo_num=mysqli_num_rows($resulthhh);

while ($rowhhh = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulthhh)) {
    $json = array(
        'posts' => array(),
    );

    $images = array();
    $image[] = $rowhhh['photo_imagedata'];
}

foreach ($image as  $ima) {
    if($photo_num==1){
        $posts['streamitem_imageuploaded']='<img  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($ima) .'" />';
    }else{
        $posts['streamitem_imageuploaded']='<img class="stream_images" style="width:235px;height:200px;object-fit:cover;margin:2px;padding:2px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($ima) .'" />';
    }
}
$json['posts'][] =  $posts;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're initializing `$images` array in each iteration of `while()` loop. Take this statement `$images = array();` outside of `while()` loop. And the same logic goes for `$json` array as well.

Also, look at the following two lines,

```
$image[] = $rowhhh['photo_imagedata'];
```

and

```
foreach ($image as  $ima) { ...
```

`$image` is *undefined*, you've to use `$images` array in those places.

So, refactor your `while()` and `foreach()` loops in the following way,

```
// your code
$photo_num=mysqli_num_rows($resulthhh);
$json = $images = array();
while ($rowhhh = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulthhh)) {
    $images[] = $rowhhh['photo_imagedata'];
}

foreach ($images as  $ima){
    $posts = array();
    if($photo_num==1){
        $posts['streamitem_imageuploaded']='<img  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($ima) .'" />';
    }else{
        $posts['streamitem_imageuploaded']='<img class="stream_images" style="width:235px;height:200px;object-fit:cover;margin:2px;padding:2px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($ima) .'" />';
    }
    $json['posts'][] =  $posts;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Working now. Glad to know I wasn't too far off.